# Owin Based authentication - No 'Configuration' method was found in web api

Tags: c#, oauth, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I never worked on authentication before and want to learn authentications in asp.net web api's

I created a project, and start working with the help of [this](https://blogs.perficient.com/2017/06/11/token-based-authentication-in-web-api-2-via-owin/)  Tutorial

But I am getting the below error

> The following errors occurred while attempting to load the app.
>   - No 'Configuration' method was found in class 'OwinBasedToken.Startup, OwinBasedToken, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. To disable OWIN startup
>   discovery, add the appSetting owin:AutomaticAppStartup with a value of
>   "false" in your web.config. To specify the OWIN startup Assembly,
>   Class, or Method, add the appSetting owin:AppStartup with the fully
>   qualified startup class or configuration method name in your
>   web.config.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.EntryPointNotFoundException: The following
>   errors occurred while attempting to load the app.
>   - No 'Configuration' method was found in class 'OwinBasedToken.Startup, OwinBasedToken, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. To disable OWIN startup
>   discovery, add the appSetting owin:AutomaticAppStartup with a value of
>   "false" in your web.config. To specify the OWIN startup Assembly,
>   Class, or Method, add the appSetting owin:AppStartup with the fully
>   qualified startup class or configuration method name in your
>   web.config.

here is my code

WebApiConfig.cs

```
using System.Web.Http;

namespace OwinBasedToken
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;
using Owin;
using OwinBasedToken.Provider;
using System;
using System.Web.Http;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(OwinBasedToken.Startup))]

namespace OwinBasedToken
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            configureOAuth(app);

            WebApiConfig.Register(config);
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }

        public void configureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60),
                Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
            };
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
        }
    }
}
```

SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider.cs

```
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace OwinBasedToken.Provider
{
    public class SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    {
        public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
        {
            context.Validated();
        }

        public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {
            context.Validated(new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType));
        }
    }
}
```

OwinTokenController

```
using System.Web.Http;

namespace OwinBasedToken.Controllers
{
    public class OwinTokenController : ApiController
    {
        [Authorize]
        public IHttpActionResult Authorize()
        {
            return Ok("Authorized");
        }
    }
}
```

I just want to know, what I am doing wrong here?

Did I missed something?

[image]

Comment: nobody ever reads exception messages :( _" No 'Configuration' method was found in class 'OwinBasedToken.Startup, OwinBasedToken, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'"_ means that there is no `Configuration` method found in your `Startup` class. Literally.

Comment: @vasily.sib I do have a method named Configuration in my Startup Class

Comment: No, you haven't

Comment: You have a method named `configuration`, but you need a method named `Configuration`. `c` != `C`

Comment: Ohhhh I didn't notice this, anyways thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your coding convention. 
In C# we are using "PascalCase". Fix your configuration and configurationOauth method to Configuration and ConfigurationOauth(optional) for work. Good luck.

P/s: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions hope this help to u

Answer (score 1):

You will need to define `Configuration`, not `configuration`:

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        configureOAuth(app);

        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
```